# Proofs and exponents to the N power

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, proof, properties

I'm still a beginner at Mathematica and I'd like to understand how to use it for proofs. Here is a simple one on exponent properties

```
(a*b)^n == a^n*b^n
```

I tried using the Truth-evaluating function in the mathematica on more complex versions of this, it does not work, even thought mathematica will recognize it when the variables are evaluated at a point (the first expand term)

```
a = 1
b = 3
c=2
n=3

(a*b+a*c)^n
(a^n)*(b+c)^n
(a*b+a*c)^n == (a^n)*(b+c)^n
Expand[%]
(x*y+x*z)^u == (x^u)*(y+z)^u
Expand[%]
```

The last line should evaluate to true, but doesn't. I'd like to understand how to do proofs related to algebraic concepts. Thanks for any help and let me know if I can make this question more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Mathematica* typically works with complex numbers. It turns out however that the identity $a^n b^n = \left(a b\right)^n$ is not generally true for all complex numbers. This can be quickly verified with `FindInstance`:

```
FindInstance[(a b)^n != a^n b^n, {a, b, n}]
```

The two major conditions this will be true is if $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ or if $a>0 \land b>0$. These can be shown to be generally true by using `Simplify` with the appropriate assumptions (in the second argument).

```
Simplify[(a b)^n == a^n b^n, {n \[Element] Integers}]
Simplify[(a b)^n == a^n b^n, {a > 0, b > 0}]
```

Both of which evaluate to `True`, as expected.

This works with the more complicated expression as well:

```
Simplify[(x*y + x*z)^u == (x^u)*(y + z)^u, {x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}]
```

> True

You may also be interested in looking at `PowerExpand`, which expands powers based on assuming the (given) variables are positive and real.

Comment: Thanks! question: what does the simplify function do in this? Why is it necessary to evaluate to true?

Comment: `Simplify` attempts to rewrite the expression to the simplest form it can find, and it can take a set of assumptions as its second argument. If a statement is universally true under a set of assumptions, then the simplest form is naturally going to be `True`. It's not the only function that could be used here, but it is one of the more general ones.